# libsaxon-HEC-setup corrupt on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, saxon

I'm hoping to use the **Saxon/C PHP integratio**n instead of running command-line executables in my php code.  However, it appears that both

- libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v0.3.1 and
- libsaxon-HEC-setup-v0.3.1

are corrupt files.  I can unzip them, but when I attempt to run the script I get a message stating

```
"Error: The installation package is corrupted, 612."
```

Has anyone else run into this issue, or do they know of a different location I can get the package from that is not corrupted?

Comment: Hi, I have not seen this error before. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the installation script works fine. Maybe try downloading the zip file again and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi did you get any further with this problem

Comment: No, I ended up making a call to the command line from my php script and running it from there.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you found a work around. However for us to improve the product it would be good to know about your environment and setup for us to investigate this problem as we would definitely like to know what went wrong and come up with a solution.

Comment: @ond1 Sure thing.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5 and my php version is 5.4.42.  You can see the phpinfo for my server (the site I want to run the code on is a different URL but the same machine) here: http://www.matthewedavis.net/phpinfo.php

When I use wget and grab the zip file (or if I download it to my local machine and use ftp to send it), unzip the file using "sudo unzip libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v0.3.1.zip", and try to run it this is what happens:

[ps11927]$ sudo ./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v0.3.1
Error: The installation package is corrupted, 612

Comment: Thanks. One other thing. You say you make a call to the command line is that invoking Saxon/C or the java version? If it is Saxon/C could you please paste an example?

Comment: I'm invoking it from the command line -- I can't get Saxon/C to install so I haven't tried to make the call from there. I'll post the code into another comment.

Comment: $line=htmlspecialchars($_GET["line"]);
$zone=htmlspecialchars($_GET["zone"]);
$collection=htmlspecialchars($_GET["collection"]);
$unique=microtime(true) . mt_rand(1,5000000000);
$filename=$unique . ".xml";
$html=$unique . ".html";

$text = exec ("java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -t -q:test.xq -o:$filename line=$line zone=$zone collection=file:/home/matrygg/minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/$collection");

$transform = exec ("java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:$filename -xsl:comparison.xsl -o:$html");

Comment: $test = file_get_contents($html);
echo $test;

unlink($filename);
unlink($html);

Comment: Sorry, the commenting isn't letting me keep the code formatting.

Comment: I can confirm the issue. On Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, I get `Error: The installation package is corrupted, 615` when looking to execute `libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.0.2`. When trying the 32-bit binary, I get an even more startling `bash: ./libsaxon-HEC-setup-v1.0.2: No such file or directory`. All of this is on my shared-hosting server; on my local Ubuntu 15.10 system everything works as expected. I'm afraid I'm going to need a solution for this.